# Path manipulation in NodeJS

Tags: node.js, path

I want to create some new paths by modifying a copy of an existing path. The Node path object seems very basic. I can see how it's possible with the default path object but it seems clunky.

What is the neatest way to change

`a/path/to/file.json`

Into two other paths

`a/path/to/file-original.json`

`a/path/to/file-comparand.json`

The path could be relative or absolute so I'm hoping for something that just allows me to change the [name](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path) without having to worry about [root](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path) or [dir](https://nodejs.org/api/path.html#path_path_parse_path) objects.

Is there an Advanced Path module or something else I'm missing?

Thanks for any help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming there's not a library which will implement this functionality for you, using `path.parse` doesn't have to be clunky - I actually think using that is probably the cleanest way of doing this:

```
let { dir, name, ext } = path.parse("a/path/to/file.json");
let path1 = path.join(dir, name + "-original" + ext);
let path2 = path.join(dir, name + "-comarand" + ext);
```

That code snippet uses [destructuring](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Destructuring_assignment), so you'll need a recent-ish version of Node to run it. That said, you could just replace that with accessing the parsed path object  normally:

```
let p = path.parse("a/path/to/file.json");
let path1 = path.join(p.dir, p.name + "-original" + p.ext);
let path2 = path.join(p.dir, p.name + "-comarand" + p.ext);
```

Not that much worse!

If this is something you'd be doing frequently in your project, it wouldn't be too hard to lift it out into a utility function, like so:

```
function suffixFilename(path, suffix) {
    let { dir, name, ext } = path.parse(path);
    return path.join(dir, name + "-" + suffix + ext);
}

let path1 = suffixFilename("a/path/to/file.json", "original");
let path2 = suffixFilename("a/path/to/file.json", "comparand");
```

Comment: This was my first thought but you will have to consider the `root` if the path is absolute. There is an `isAbsolute` function in the path object but then the code becomes quite complex for something so simple. I presumed I must be missing something.

Comment: @moefinley: I'm not sure I follow - `dir` always includes the `root` of the path (if it has one), so this method should handle relative and absolute paths. That said, I don't have access to a proper Node environment on this PC, so I can't test that to be certain!

Comment: D'oh, yes you're right. I think I miss read the documentation. Thanks.

Comment: @moefinley: To be fair, it's not hugely clear! Glad I could help.

Answer (score 0):

In addition to @joe's answer, here's a simpler version that needs the  [`modify-filename`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/modify-filename) package.

```
var modifyFilename = require('modify-filename');
const originalPath = "a/path/to/file.json";

const originalFilename = modifyFilename(originalPath, (name, ext) => {
    return `${name}-original${ext}`;
});

const comparandFilename = modifyFilename(originalPath, (name, ext) => {
    return `${name}-comparand${ext}`;
});
```

Comment: The use of a callback to make the function more reusable is quite a nice way to design this, actually :)